# Is More Math Important For This Site?

Tags: discussion

A quick glance at Physics SE shows that there is a lot more math used on that site, generally in answers. Granted, there are a lot of physics concepts (not including those oh-so-treacherous homework-style problems) that can only be explained using math, but there is a conspicuous usage of math in answers there, and an equally conspicuous lack of math here, even on similar topics, such as general relativity. I often even get the feeling that (shudder) Astronomy SE gets the "softer" questions.

Does anyone think this is an issue (I'm currently not leaning one way or another)? Should we encourage math usage where it is relevant, or will that simply leave us with a bunch of unnecessary calculations?

Comment: I see a lot of "how do I find the exact position of..." or "how do I compute the exact time/date of...", and think that, yes, we do need more math.