# Are questions asking for help with calculations and results on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

As the title states, are questions that ask for help with calculations, or help with the results of the said calculations, on-topic? or are they off-topic, and would have a better home on a site like Physics.SE, or Mathematics.SE, or elsewhere?

---

**Some Specific Context:**

I'm working on a little side-project relating to orbits and orbital positions of objects in our solar system. I am relatively new to the mathematics behind orbital mechanics, and my understanding goes as far as what I have read online (and a few hundred hours of Kerbal Space Program...).

I have managed to adapt what I have learnt into some code to calculate cartesian and spherical coordinates. However, when I have fact-checked the output against records on [JPL's HORIZONS System](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) some of the results are not what I am expecting to see.

So I would like to ask about my understanding and implementation of the calculations, and whether I am interpreting my results correctly.

---

Checking in the Help Center, I would say that this question probably falls under *Planetary Science and Celestial mechanics*, but there does not seem to be any pointer as to whether help with calculations is something that is accepted on this site.

I also had a quick search for *Maths* and *Calculations* here on Meta, and the only two questions that seem relevant ([this one](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254/is-more-math-important-for-this-site), and [this one](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340/are-questions-that-require-calculations-off-topic)) do not answer the question.

Comment: I just ran across this question and I'm surprised to see that it's been viewed 62 times and has received 3 up votes but nobody has posted any kind of response to it. My feeling is that Python's [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-eafp) ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11360880), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32901991), but [not in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/404795)) applies in this case. The site is pretty friendly and so a reasonable question is not likely to quickly collect down votes, and instead if there are issues they'd be brought up in helpful comments.

Comment: This question could likely have also been asked in [Space Exploration SE](https://space.stackexchange.com/) as well. I know it's been almost two years now, I hope you were able to resolve your issues independently.